# boostrap modal doesnt show up

Tags: php, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

please help, i have a bootstrap template with this footer , i trying to add a modal but when i click the modal button,the modal doesnt show up , is there any plugin that have not been added in my template ?

```
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter.js')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min')?>"></script>
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js')?>"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="<?= base_url('template/assets/js/main.js')?>"></script>
```

and this the modal button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your code contains bootstrap CSS and Bootstrap Js.
Like,

```
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"> 
  </script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Bootstrap5** than change **data-toggle** to **data-bs-toggle** and **data-target** to **data-bs-target**.